# How do I return an option saved to the Laravel database?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I am programming a system in Laravel 5.8 and nenessito do the editing of the user through a select but when I make the request does not appear the option that the user selected.

I already tried to pass the Controller attractive but not right.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $users = User::find($id);
    $institutions = Institution::all('razaosocial');
    return view('users.edit', compact(array('users','institutions')));
}

<div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{Form::label('Instituição:')}}
                <select class=form-control name="instituicao" id="instituicao">
                    <option value="null">Selecione uma Instituição</option>
                    @foreach($institutions as $institution)

                    <option value="{{$institution->razaosocial}}">
                        {{ $institution->razaosocial}}
                    </option>

                    @endforeach
                </select>


            </div>
      </div>
```

I hope that appears in the view the option selects by during registration.

Comment: What was the error displayed for this code? Note errors are not there to tell you what went wrong but also what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping something works in programming is very frustrating and I am at the moment. compact() actually creates an associative array whose keys are variable names and their corresponding values are array values. So instead of

```
compact(array('users','institutions'));
```

make it

```
compact('users','institutions');
```

Here is a reference that solves this problem
[Laravel: Display data in DropDown from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878335/laravel-display-data-in-dropdown-from-database)

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks